# Where is "gcc_tooldir"

Tags: compiling, gcc, gnu, configure

Under [Cross-Compiler-Specific Options](//gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html#Cross-Compiler-Specific-Options), it says:

> The default value, in case `--with-sysroot` is not given an argument, is
>   `${gcc_tooldir}/sys-root`.

but it appears that `gcc_tooldir` is not defined. Is this a nickname for
something else, and also where is it "normally"?

Comment: Just to be clear: it is your intention to build a cross-compiling version of GCC, but not to build the GNU C library from the same source tree, yes?  Because that's the use case for the `--with-sysroot` option.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes http://github.com/svnpenn/glade/blob/master/mingw-w64-x86-64/gcc/install.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it appears that gcc_tooldir is not defined. Is this a nickname for something else, and also where is it "normally"?

`gcc_tooldir` is a `make` variable.  You should find that within the scope of a GCC build, it has a value that is functionally equivalent to that of the `$(tooldir)` make variable, but somewhat different in form.  You are not meant to set it by hand, though you may of course use the `--with-sysroot` configure option to choose your own directory for the target tools.  Per [the GCC build documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/finalinstall.html):

> When installing cross-compilers, GCC’s executables are not only installed into `bindir`, that is, `exec-prefix`/bin, but additionally into `exec-prefix`/`target-alias`/bin, if that directory exists. Typically, such *tooldirs* hold target-specific binutils, including assembler and linker.

(Emphasis in the original.)

The standard tooldir name is thus something of the form '/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32', to lift one from the Glade example you presented in comments.